# kendo window doesn't fire ng-controller in remote content file

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-window

http://plnkr.co/edit/waprosDnTh1c8zxHNkPN?p=preview

I have a button that calls `showNewDialog()` when clicked. It launches a new kendo window loading from a remote content file. However, if I specify an ng-controller attribute in a div inside the remote content file, it doesn't seems to fire the ng-controller.

From the remote content file, I have an example of printing the `$scope.hello` variable that is already initiated inside `MyCtrl`. Instead of processing the `$scope.hello` variable, the raw syntax output is given.

Have any of you guys encounter this problem before?

A plunker link is attached as well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to dynamically generate kendo window cannot be recognized by angular, instead you should use `kendo-window` attribute

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview&s=Kh4syZajQnoc9Xn1